# Kubernetes rolling deployment using the yaml file

Tags: kubernetes

I have deployed an application into Kubernetes using the following command.

```
kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml -n <NAMESPACE>
```

I have my deployment content in the deployment yaml file.

This is working fine. Now, I have updated few things in the deployment.yaml file and hence would like to update the deployment.

**Option 1:- Delete and deploy again**

```
kubectl delete -f deployment.yaml -n <NAMESPACE>
kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml -n <NAMESPACE>
```

**Option 2:- Use set to update changes**

```
kubectl set image deployment/nginx-deployment nginx=nginx:1.91
```

I don't want to use this approach as I am keeping my deployment.yaml file in GitHUB.

**Option 3:- Using edit command**

```
kubectl edit deployment/nginx-deployment
```

I don't want to use the above 3 options.

Is there any way to update the deployment using the file itself.

Like,

```
kubectl update deployment.yaml -n NAMESPACE
```

This way, I will make sure that I will always have the latest deployment file in my GitHub repo.

Comment: What about just `kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml` without the `kubectl delete` first? (My understanding is that the *point* of `kubectl apply` is to perform a smart diff/patch, so doing it after `kubectl delete` seems a little odd.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Daisy Shipton has said, what you want to do could be simplified with a simple command: `kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml`.

**I will also add that I don't think it's correct to utilize the *Option 2* to update the image utilized by the `Pod` with an imperative command!** If the source of truth is the `Deployment` file present on your GitHub, you should simply update that file, by modifying the image that is used by your Pod's container there!

- Next time you desire to update your `Deployment` object, unless you don't forget to modify the .yaml file, you will be setting the Pods to use the previous Nginx's image.

So there certainly should exist some restriction in using imperative commands to update the specification of any Kubernetes's object!